# Python: subsetting multiple elements

Tags: python

Given

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

how can I subset elements 0 and 2 (i.e., ["a", "c"])?

Comment: Surely you don't have trouble writing `[mylist[0], mylist[1]]`? So please describe what do you *really* want to do.

Comment: I want something like mylist[0,2] (where [0,2] is a list of the element positions I want).

Answer (score 8):

Although this is not the usual way to use itemgetter,

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> itemgetter(0,2)(mylist)
('a', 'c')
```

If the indices are already in a list - use `*` to unpack it

```
>>> itemgetter(*[0,2])(mylist)
('a', 'c')
```

You an also use a list comprehension

```
>>> [mylist[idx] for idx in [0,2]]
['a', 'c']
```

or use map

```
>>> map(mylist.__getitem__, [0,2])
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: please, don't tell people to use map that way. BTW, don't tell people to use map...

Comment: @Franklin, `map` is still a solid part of Python. It's still a builtin in Python3 and has even been improved to return an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: Yeah if it's so solid then why it changed? And why Guido wanted to remove it?

Comment: Franklin, why don't you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)? You might see when and why someone might use map instead of list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehensions are much more straightforward. Can't see a single reason to use map.

Comment: @Franklin, the point of the answer @utku links to is that the use of map is quite polarizing. I think people learning Python would see the LC here and think it is more readable than map and agree with you. However `map` is commonly used in many other programming languages, so people coming from those languages may find `map` more natural than the LC. The more important thing to me is that neither method has many places for bugs to creep in compared to say, doing the same thing in C

Comment: @Franklin, I consider `map` more legible in some cases, for example I prefer `map(int, ["1", "2", "3"]` over `[int(x) for x in ["1","2","3","4"]]`.

Answer (score 3):

For fancy indexing you can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays.

```
>>> mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> import numpy
>>> myarray = numpy.array(mylist)
>>> myarray
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> myarray[[0,2]]
array(['a', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: @Mark, If answer is perfect for you, you should mark it as accepted. to do that, simply click on the tick outline.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution (among many):

```
[mylist[i] for i in [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want every second one, `mylist[::2]`.